# unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

This is the code I'm working on and getting this error

```py
def bowling_score(player_name, team):
    try:
        bow_obj = Players.objects.get(name=player_name)
    except:
        import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
    u = math.sqrt(bow_obj.bowling_appered/bow_obj.total_matches)
    v = 10*bow_obj.five_wicket_haul + bow_obj.total_wickets_taken
    w = bow_obj.bowling_average + bow_obj.econmy
    bowling_score = 0
    if w:
        bowling_score = u*v//w
    return bowling_score
```

My error
`unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'NoneType'`

Comment: Can you please post the whole errro. which line is causing the error?

Comment: print the values for ```bow_obj.total_wickets_taken```, ```bow_obj.bowling_average```, ```bow_obj.econmy```, I'm sure one of them is ```None```. And you can't add a float and a None

Answer (score 0):

Seems one of the operands is None, so addition can't complete. You can't add a float value to None (or the other way around). Check the condition of the variable/attribute holding *None* first and decide what should happen in either case.

You also aren't asking a question, you just give us some facts. So what is your question and what do you want to achieve?

Next time, don't copy the error output into the title field; ask a question instead.